# Get executing assembly name from referenced DLL in MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am building a cross platform library and at some point I want to get the executing assembly name from within the dll.

In windows I use:

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName
```

and I get something like "MyApp.exe"

However this does not work "as expected" in monotouch. When running on iOS it returns "MonoTouch"

Is there any way, using code that will compile on windows,monotouch,monodroid to get the executing assembly name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ().Location;
var name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName (path);
```

Comment: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location returns the .dll location. I want to get the executable name, the one that references the dll. (.exe in windows, .app in iOS)

Comment: Use GetEntryAssembly () instead then.

Comment: Thanks Rolf, GetEntryAssembly did the job